# How to test a Hibernate Entity without Caching

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, jpa

How can I solve the following Problem in a cleaner way?

I want to write a JUnit-Test for a StatelessServiceBean, that uses Hibernate/JPA Entities to persist and load some Data. The Service is called with DTOs (pojos with no Hibernate-context) and not with Hibernate Entities.

The TestCase should persist data and load it again to test the persistence. The Table in the DB unfortunatly has some triggers wich change the inserted data. The TestCase expects to see this changes after loading the Entity.

Pseudo Code:

```
class PersonDTO
    name
    address
    id

@Entity
@Table(name="Person")
class PersonEntity 
    name
    address
    id

@Stateless
class ServiceBean
    PersonDTO loadPerson(id)

    void persistPerson(PersonDTO person)

class Test
    testPersistAndLoad() {
        PersonDTO dto = new PersonDTO();

        service.persistPerson(dto);
        PersonDTO resultDTO = service.loadPerson(dto.getId());

        assertDTOHasBeenChangedByMagicTrigger(resultDTO);
    }
```

But Hibernate loads the Entity from the cache and return the exact same instance of the Entity that has been used to persist the data.

Currently I use a refresh() in the ServiceBean.loadPerson() on the Entity to force Hibernate to load the Entity from the DB and not only from the cache. But this is only necessary for testing, I don't want to have the refresh()-Calls in the ServiceBean.

Are there any alternatives to force Hibernate to refresh the Cache? Something that could be configured in the persistence.xml maybe?

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: Is Caching enabled in your persistence.xml?

Comment: I think this the first-level-cache which is active by default and cannot be deactivated... as far as I understand...

Comment: 2nd-Level-Caching is not active

Comment: Could you try looking up another stateless service? It should be returned a different one, with a different PersistenceContext associated (every operation with its own service)?

Comment: Your test is probably transactional, and shouldn't be. If you want to model the reality in your test,then a first transaction should be used to update the row, and a second one to reload it. In that case, a new session will be associated with the second transaction, and it will re-read the data from the database. If you want the new state to be visible even inside the same session, then refreshing is what you need.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Yes it is transactional and I write and read within the same transaction... I will try to use different Transactions.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Mmhh, I'm using setRollbackOnly() to be sure that no testdata remain in the DB. If I use more then one transaction I'd have to commit the data to the DB and cleanup manually... So I'd rather prefer another way - if there is one...

Comment: You could clear the session from inside your test.

Comment: @JB Nizet: That's the solution thx!